# css variable width div within a fixed width div

Tags: html, css

**Context:** (simplified)

```
<div style="width:300px;" >
    <img src="blabla..." />
    <div style="oveflow:hidden; etc..." >
        description
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
Sometimes the description can be very long and gets cut (intended, see "overflow:hidden;"). So I made it so that when the user hover the description a css animation pushes the description to the left side a bit, let's say "margin-left:-200px;". This way the user can continue reading the description while it reveals itself (css animate).
Now comes the issue: the description can vary from long to very long to very very long. And obviously pushing it to the left for -200px is sometimes not enough, sometimes too much.

**Solutions I know:**
1)

```
Javascript/jQuery
```

My website is full non-js and very lightweight, I do not want to use js. I found many solutions on the web using js, I already know them. Please respect this. I would love to solve it via pure css.

2)

```
<marquee>description</marquee>
```

Depreciated.

**Ideas:**
I was thinking about "tricking" it using PHP code. For example I would calculate the description's length so that I could set a "margin-left:-???px;" accordingly. Now that sounds even uglier than js to me, forcing me to "hardcode" it in the php file bypassing the conveniant css stylesheet and resulting in a heavy php file. Irrelevant.
I didn't find anything in the CSS3 about it eventhough many other designers came accross this issue from what I could find searching on GG. Is it beyond css language's scope?
Thank you.

PS: my description MUST fit in **1 line**. No line break, no scrollbar, no "show more" button, etc.

Comment: use **Pure JS**, your website will still be lightweight.

Comment: Have you considered how this will work with touch on mobile devices?

Comment: This problem has been solved by amazon / trip advisor etc on reviews - see how they did it. Note how they use a gradient at bottom to give visual cue that there is more content hidden

Comment: Allow me to insist: My description must fit in 1 line. I don't want tricks such as a toggle on/off link to "show more". Yes, I did consider touchscreen devices: they won't be displayed the description. As I said, I'm very short on space for the descriptions within these particular divs. Basically, the whole description must fit within a 300*15px div.

Comment: Are you just designing for one platform / browser / machine then? I strongly suggest you do some user testing to see if your design works. If you have not yet discovered it, Krug's Rocket Surgery book is a great start.

Comment: It's crossplateform. The description is just a fancy UX "plus" for desktop users, it does not contain critical informations, that's why I'm trying to fit it in a 300*15px div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest I could come.

I am slightly concerned that the `slide` eventually end with the description hidden but I think that's a small price to pay...otherwise I think it meets most of the criteria

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border:1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap img {
  max-height:100%;
  width: auto;
}

.desc {
  width: 300px;
  height: 15px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap .desc p{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 5s ease;
}

.wrap:hover .desc p{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" >
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="desc" >
        <p>Tri-tip shank turkey chuck, porchetta drumstick andouille beef ribs prosciutto salami beef. Ham hock pork belly pig pastrami. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qOOeVE)

Comment: That is as close as we can get using css apparently. Thank you for the "display:flex;", I never heard about it. IE<10 does not support it but it's ok.

Comment: Well the layout could be done without flexbox...any normal method would work...I just default to flexbox these days. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. you could use echo `<br/>` with php when a certain length is reached
   each time.
2. you could use css `max-width` property to restrict the width to a
   certain amount

Comment: My description must fit in 1 line.

Comment: so count the content. make the font-size small.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

```
p.test {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope. My description must fit in 1 line. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest you is fix the width and height of the description div and use the css property overflow-y:auto.

The default scrollbar is ugly and different for all the browsers so you may try a js plugin but as you said you don't want to add a library just to achieve a small task.:)

Comment: This does not lead to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm very short in space for that description div. I dont want neither line brakes nor scrollbars :(

Comment: can you show me the exact proposal that you are trying to implement.

Comment: The whole description must fit within a 300*15px div, 1 line max.

Comment: are you allowed to show the whole content in a popup?
i mean some content can be shown in 300*15px and then whole description can be shown in a popup when clicked on read more button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
div.test {
        white-space: nowrap; 
        width: 12em; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        height:30px;   
    }
    div.test:hover {
        text-overflow: inherit;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    <p>Hover over the two divs below, to see the entire text.</p>

    <div class="test" style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">This is some long text that will not fit in the box. This is some long text that will not fit in the boxThis is some long text that will not fit in the boxThis is some long text that will not fit in the boxThis is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
    <br>
    <div class="test" style="text-overflow:clip;">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

Comment: "overflow:visible;" will make it expand all over the rest of the page's design. I'm already using the "text-overflow:ellipsis;" already (I removed un-necessary codes in my original post). There was a reason why I am currently doing "margin-left:-***px;", it's because I can't use "overflow:visible;" ;-D